# I want to add first and last digit of the number

Tags: java

I want to add first and last digit of the number.Here I used arraylist to take any number of input.Like I want to give input 3,103,2045 for single digit number should be ommited,then the output must be 4(103 the last digit is 3 and first digit is 1) and 7(similarly for 2045).I tried this but it's not terminating.

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class add {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();


     while(scan.hasNextInt()){
       list.add(scan.nextInt());
                             }

  Integer [] num = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);

  for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
   {
     int temp=0;
     while(num[i]>=10)
      {
      temp=num[i]%10;

      while(num[i]>1)
     {
     num[i]=num[i]%10;

     }   
     temp=num[i]+temp;
    }
 System.out.println(""+temp);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: *3,103,2045 then the output must be 4 and 7.I* WHY?????

Comment: Try writing a separate method that takes an `int` and decomposes it into its separate decimal digits as an array of `ints`. Then add the first non-zero digit and the last digit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not terminating is the following infinite loop:

```
while (num[i]>1) {
    num[i]=num[i]%10;
}
```

The first iteration of that loop will assign a single digit number in `num[i]`. The second iteration and any other iteration will not change the value of `num[i]`, since the remainder of dividing a single digit number by 10 is that same single digit number. You probably wanted to perform division - `num[i]=num[i]/10;`

The correct logic (for a single input) should look like this:

```
int lastDigit=num[i] % 10; // the last (least significant digit) is easy to find
if (num[i] > lastDigit) { // only numbers with multiple digits will be handled
    while(num[i] >= 10) { // loop until you find the first (most significant) digit
        num[i] = num[i] / 10;
    }
}
int sum = lastDigit + num[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract a method that will compute the digit sum (if value is less than 10):

```
private static Optional<Integer> sumDigits(Integer number){
        if(number<10) {return Optional.empty();} // single digit number

        int lastDigit = number%10; // compute last digit

        while(number>9){ // reduce number to get first digt
           number = number/10;
        }

        return Optional.of(number + lastDigit);
  }
```

Eventually, you could convert number to String, and simply pick the digits. But this is much less efficient in java.

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class DigitSum {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

     while(scan.hasNextInt()){
       sumDigits(scan.nextInt()).ifPresent(list::add);
     }
   }
  private static Optional<Integer> sumDigits(Integer number){
        if(number<10) {retrun Optional.empty();} // single digit number

        String numberAsString = number.toString();
        return Optional.of(Integer.parse(numberAsString.charAt(0)) +
               Integer.parse(numberAsString.charAt(numberAsString.length-1)));

  }
}
```

or yousing your approach with modulo (much faster):

Answer (score 0):

could you possibly... split the String?

```
String input = "3,103,2047";
String [] strs = input.split(",");
for(String str : strs){
    System.out.println(Integer.parse(str.charAt(0)) + Integer.parse(str.charAt(str.length -1)));
}
```

you would need some data checking so it doesn't throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(if str.length == 1, maybe?) error, or an error if you pass something other then numbers and ','